# System changes power mode to Power Saver a few minutes after rebooting

Tags: boot, laptop, windows-8.1, power-supply

*Laptop: Samsung NP3530EC-A0DDX, running Windows 8.1*

For some reason, every time I happen to be booting my laptop, the power mode constantly changes to Power Saver after about five minutes since boot. Usually, I always use High Performance, and I nearly always keep my laptop plugged in anyways.

I doubt that there is an issue with the charger, and this kind of change normally doesn't happen at all, only on this occasion where I boot my laptop.

**How can I prevent this?**

Comment: Any Samsung running tool which could affect this?

Comment: @davidbaumann I haven't been able to find anything like that that causes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be nearly identical to [this question asked on the Microsoft forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/windows-81-power-plan-always-reverts-to-power/f11a65e0-8f7a-4ce0-8be7-58f2fef3536e?auth=1). You may need to look again at the installed programs (look in the Start Menu, Task tray, and the Control Panel thoroughly) to make sure that app isn't hiding somewhere.

> Samsung computers come with some power saving app (Fast Start etc.) preinstalled, this software overrides Windows power options settings and automatically changes the power settings to power saving mode. Check your computer for any such software. Some of our community members have got this problem resolved by disabling or uninstalling it.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'll have a go and see if this could work.